# in pycharm, how can I call and step into a function that is open in the editor with breakpoints set

Tags: pycharm

I am new to pycharm and trying out community edition.

My standalone program script contains multiple functions. Before I run the whole program I want to quickly test the functions standalone by calling then with parameters, step into them, stop at any breakpoints defined in the editor UI.

I don't want to run the top level program itself each time to test each standalone function. I don't want to create different configurations with different parameters combinations. I just want to run the function right now and stop at any breakpoints i've set in the editor.

In Pycharm I can see my program structure (all its functions and params) in the Structure window. I was hoping to right click my function and see a menu item with a name like "Call this function", supply any parameters and step into it. Or maybe call the function from a console type window. But execution needs to stop at breakpoints I already defined in the code editor UI.

---

If it helps define the requirement, Microsoft VBA and Powershell provide a Console style window in order to call any functions in the current module. I can call any function by entering the call and any parameters, hit return, and it will display any return vals e.g...

MyFunction("SMITH")

Employee SMITH has ID 1234

Code stops at any breakpoints defined in the VBA/Powershell UI Code Editor.
If I want to reexecute with different parameters, I just change my existing call and hit return, or paste in a new one etc. The result is that I can very quickly and easily test my functions individually.

Answer (score 3):

Python itself doesn't really have a concept of cranking up the interpreter and calling something without being told to. Python does, though, have a convention for modules that can be directly executed. Just use the:

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    your_function()
```

block at the bottom. You'll have to edit the `your_function` part, of course, but that's easier than going through your application.